# Can V8 JavaScript engine call an external library or function?

Tags: javascript, linux, chromium, v8

I would like to build a Linux application that will run Chromium as a browser, V8 as the JavaScript engine and allow access to the operating system via JavaScript, primarily for file storage functions such as write file, read file, delete file, get file listing. Is there a way to configure or modify the V8 JavaScript engine that will allow JavaScript code to call a function in an external library? Or is there another architecture that would achieve the same end result?

Edit: this is for a client side application, essentially a media player that can download video files and play them from the local drive.

Comment: You need more detail. What languages are you looking to call?
Like for C++ there is https://nodejs.org/api/addons.html
For file system support there is https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Have you done any research prior to asking?

Comment: Might you be trying to do what electron already does?? https://electronjs.org/

Comment: @asosnovsky Language is not an issue Ill code it in whichever language the architecture is provided. I thought we were allowed to ask questions here as part of research.

Comment: @Intervalia thank you, that certainly looks like a better idea.

Comment: "V8 as server-side Javascript engine" is the definition of NodeJS.

Comment: In what sense is this an [embedded] tag question?

Answer (score 0):

By default, chromium runs the V8 engine in a sandbox, disallowing (among other things) access to local files.

More in-depth description: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkcr/docs/linux_sandboxing.md

You're looking for the `--no-sandbox` switch on chrome/chromium. That will grant you access to local files. After that you can go nuts with the JavaScript file API: https://w3c.github.io/FileAPI/#filereader-interface